# Get sub type parameter from a type parameter

Tags: scala, generics

Let's build up some context. `Data` composes of `Metadata` and `Payload`.

```
trait Data[Metadata <: Product, Payload <: Product] extends Product {
  def metadata: Metadata
  def payload: Payload
}

case class M()
case class P()
case class D(metadata: M, payload: P) extends Data[M, P]
```

I have `Processor` to process `Metadata` and `Payload` differently.

```
trait MetadataProcessor[Metadata <: Product] {
  def apply() = "process metadata"
}
trait PayloadProcessor[Payload <: Product] {
  def apply() = "process payload"
}

// both work
new MetadataProcessor[M]{}.apply() // "process metadata"
new PayloadProcessor[P]{}.apply() // "process payload"
```

I hope `DataProcessor` to be able to process both `Metadata` and `Payload`. This is one way:

```
trait DataProcessor[Metadata <: Product, Payload <: Product] {
  def apply() = {
        new MetadataProcessor[Metadata]{}.apply() +
        new PayloadProcessor[Payload]{}.apply()   
  }
}
new DataProcessor[M,P]{}.apply() // "process metadataprocess payload"
```

However, I want to call `new DataProcessor[D]{}.apply()` and gets exactly the same output. How to do it?

For an interactive Scala environment with above code, feel free to look at [Scastie playground](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9G66NISMStSZrqlyh17ETg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make `Metadata` and `Payload` [type members rather than type parameters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8GksuRw3VI) and use type projections `Data#Metadata`, `Data#Payload`.

```
trait Data extends Product {
  type Metadata <: Product
  type Payload <: Product
  def metadata: Metadata
  def payload: Payload
}

  // This is optional, just in case if you need also type parameters Metadata and Payload.
  // Then you can use them as Data.Aux[Metadata, Payload]
//  object Data {
//    type Aux[Metadata0 <: Product, Payload0 <: Product] = Data { type Metadata = Metadata0; type Payload = Payload0 }
//  }

case class M()
case class P()
case class D(metadata: M, payload: P) extends Data { type Metadata = M; type Payload = P }

trait MetadataProcessor[Metadata <: Product] {
  def apply() = "process metadata"
}
trait PayloadProcessor[Payload <: Product] {
  def apply() = "process payload"
}

new MetadataProcessor[M]{}.apply() // "process metadata"
new PayloadProcessor[P]{}.apply() // "process payload"

trait DataProcessor[A <: Data] {
  def apply() = {
    new MetadataProcessor[A#Metadata]{}.apply() +
      new PayloadProcessor[A#Payload]{}.apply()
  }
}

new DataProcessor[D]{}.apply() // "process metadataprocess payload"
```